# If X (an NP-hard problem) is polynomial-time many-one reducible to problem Y, then Y is NP-hard. Why is it the case?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, np

According to [this](https://gatecse.in/some_reduction_inferences/) source,

> If A is reduced to B and A ∈ class X, then B cannot be easier than X.  This reduction is used to show if a problem belongs to NPH – just reduce some known NPH problem to the given problem. This reduction thus gives a lower bound for the complexity of B.

Now consider the following scenario: X is an NP-hard problem. It is polynomial-time many-one reducible to problem Y. This makes Y NP-hard. My question is, it could be possible that X has a better solution like NP or P, which we could not find. Then why should Y be NP-hard? It could be NP or P. If Y turns out to be P (assume) then X becomes P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All NP-complete problems are "equally hard", in the sense that if one of them is in P, then all of them are in P. Similarly, if one NP-complete problem can be solved in quasipolynomial time (that is, time $e^{O(\log^C n)}$ for some constant $C$) then all of them can be solved in quasipolynomial time.

Some NP-hard problems are harder than others, but all of them are at least as hard as all NP-complete problem. That is, if some NP-hard problem is in P, then all NP-complete problems are in P. Similarly, if some NP-hard problem can be solved in quasipolynomial time, then the same holds for all NP-complete problems.

However, some NP-hard problems are *provably* harder than others. For example, the halting problem is NP-hard, but in contrast to all NP-complete problems, it cannot be solved in exponential time; in fact, it cannot be decided at all!

---

> My question is, it could be possible that X has a better solution like NP or P, which we could not find.

There are two problems with this statement. The first is the assumption that NP is a better complexity class than NP-hard. In fact, all NP-complete problems are both NP-hard and in NP (that's the definition of NP-completeness), so it's in fact common for problems to be both. NP-hardness is a *lower bound* on complexity, whereas being in NP is an *upper bound*. The two are not contradictory in any way.

The second problem is the assumption that it could be possible that X is in P. As explained above, that would imply that P=NP, which most people consider unlikely. An NP-hard problem cannot be "easy" – it's at least as hard as any problem in NP, and in particular at least as hard an any NP-complete problem.

---

> Then why should Y be NP-hard?

You can prove that Y is NP-hard if you can reduce, in polynomial time, another NP-hard problem X to it. I won't repeat the proof here, since it can be found in textbooks, lecture notes, and even here on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

---

> If Y turns out to be P (assume) then X becomes P.

That's correct, but there is no contradiction here. This is actually the point of NP-hardness. We don't believe that Y is in P, since that would imply that X, as well as many other problems, are also in P.